# Having one part of a model be one connected UV Map

Tags: texturing, uv

I have just started looking more into UV Mapping and it looks significantly harder than I thought, I have this model and I am having trouble mapping out the individual parts of the model in into one UV island.

[image]

So for example, I want all the blue parts of the model to be a singular connected UV island, so if I were to put a texture on it, it wouldn't have any seams or be distorted.

I'm sorry if this is a newbie question but I am not familiar with this stuff.

Thanks

Comment: Having a quads based modeling topology (instead of triangle based) generally helps with unwrapping. Start by mark some seams on your model before unwrapping, then if you select all the blue faces at once and unwrap them, they should mostly be kept as a single island as far as I know.

Comment: Just to make this process a little clearer, when you unwrap the model what are you exactly looking for in the UV? What differentiates a good UV from a bad UV, and since blender just has the Smart UV, what prevents me from just doing that? (Sorry about the amount of questions)

Comment: The documentation is quite complete about unwrapping https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping/introduction.html.

Comment: Bad UV map is the one which makes texture look distorted, the good one does the other way around. To check that use checker board texture (in the options of creating new image choose UV Grid) and enable displaying textures in viewport. There shuld be seams on that mesh; you can texture paint over them afterwards (with Clone brush). The thing is that at least 2 or maybe even more seams for that mesh are needed; think of it if you're going to unfold paper figure of that form.

Comment: Actually, someone mentioned somewhere that you can Texture bake to find all the seams and paint them out, how does that work?